# python selenium TimeUnit - where to import from

Tags: python, selenium

I'm using Python selenium version 3.0.1 in which it seems that instead of saying

```
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
```

we must now say

```
driver.implicitly_wait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
```

This gives me the error ...

*NameError: name 'TimeUnit' is not defined*

So I need to import TimeUnit, but where (what module) do I import it from?

The documentation link at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium takes me to selenium 2 documentation, and typing TimeUnit into the search box there draws a blank.  So anyone who wants to tell me to read the docs needs to tell me where the right docs are.

Comment: Why do you think that `implicitly_wait()` should takes 2 arguments?

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea about what `TimeUnit.SECONDS` is, but no matter what it is `implicitly_wait()`  takes only one argument!

```
>>> help(driver.implicitly_wait)
Help on method implicitly_wait in module     selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver:

implicitly_wait(time_to_wait) method of     selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver.Web
Driver instance
Sets a sticky timeout to implicitly wait for an element to be found,
   or a command to complete. This method only needs to be called one
   time per session. To set the timeout for calls to
   execute_async_script, see set_script_timeout.

:Args:
 - time_to_wait: Amount of time to wait (in seconds)

:Usage:
    driver.implicitly_wait(30)
```

So if you try to send any 2 arguments, you should get

> TypeError: implicitly_wait() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

P.S. Also do not forget that first positional argument in this case is `self` which   refers to object itself

Answer (score 2):

There is a small difference between the selenium interface for Java and python. Java expect explicit time units, while python has the time units implicit in the function call (e.g. just a number no units). See for example https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp for code examples in both java and python. The Timeunit library is purely used in Java and you can find the documentation here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html.

Answer (score 2):

TimeUnit is an APi from Java, not from Seelnium.

Use the below command to import it:

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit

Answer (score 1):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import time

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
```